# Dynamic Play! template links

Tags: java, html, groovy, playframework

I"m having trouble generating dynamic links from strings.  I have a controller which renders a page:

```
public class ViewController extends Controller {
   public static void index() {
      Map<String, String> breadcrumbsMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
      breadcrumbsMap.put("Home", "ViewController.index()");
      breadcrumbsMap.put("User", "UserController.index()");

      render(breadcrumbsMap);
   }
}
```

The page has markup that looks like (but doesn't work):

```
<ul id="breadcrumbs">
    #{list items:breadcrumbsMap.keySet(), as:'key'}
       <li>#{a @breadcrumbsMap.get(key)}${key}#{/a}</li> 
    #{/list}
</ul>
```

I can't figure out how to make the markup turn the string into a link.  From the docs, something standard would be:

```
#{a @Application.logout()}Disconnect#{/a}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
breadcrumbsMap.put("Home", Router.reverse("ViewController.index()", emptyMap).url);
breadcrumbsMap.put("User", Router.reverse("UserController.index()", emptyMap).url);
```

And display the link like any string:

```
<a href="breadcrumbsMap.get(key)">${key}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="breadcrumbsMap.get(key)">&{key}</a>
```

Comment: actually, did yours get formatted?  <a href="${breadcrumbsMap.get(key)}">&{key}</a>